# High quality rendering

Tags: rendering

I want to render an image in 4k quality. The questions are:

1. What data should be followed in order for it to turn out well? Is it enough to change only the resolution or do you need to change more data?
2. I tried to render several times, it rendered until the end but at the end of the rendering the image disappeared.
   What could be the reason this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: 1. How should we answer that? It depends on your scene. If you have a low resolution sphere for example it might look okay in a smaller image, but on a larger image the shape might not be smooth enough. This is just one of I guess hundreds of things that might be different if you render larger.
2. Did you change any default performance settings? Blender uses tiling which is by default set to 2048 pixels. Which means, when you are rendering a 4k image, it will be rendered in 4 tiles. So are you 100% sure the render was finished or was just one of the tiles finished?

Comment: Check your setup in the compositor to ensure everything is connected properly. This can make a render disappear at the very end after it was looking fine during rendering.